# Strange boolean behavior in Clojure with checkbox in form-data

Tags: clojure, boolean, compojure

I'm using an AngularJS resource to basically $.ajax() some form data.

```
Post.put({user:$scope.getLoggedInUser(), action:"new"},{body:$scope.postBody, "public":$scope.postPublic}, function(post) {
```

On the form is a checkbox named "public."

I am using this function to merge the form data with the params from the URL:

```
(defn get-params [request]
  (merge (:params request) (parse-string (slurp (request :body)) true)))
```

when I println from my route's handler like so I get a nice `true` when the checkbox is checked:

```
(println (:public (get-params request)))
```

However, when I pass the parameter (i.e. not the println) to another function in my controller that talks to the database, I do another println at the beginning of that function and get `nil` instead.

I've tried passing it as

```
(read-string x)
(boolean (Boolean/valueOf x))
(Boolean/valueOf x)
```

to no avail.

One thing that might be causing it (but I don't know why) is that I'm wrapping the request through authentication like this:

```
(auth? request #(create x y z))
```

where the `(create)` function creates a record in the database.

I can't get it to be `true` no matter what I've tried.

***EDIT: more complete code***

**CONTROLLER**

```
(defn auth? [request callback-true & [callback-false]]
  (println (callback-true))
  (let [login-response (auth/login request)]
    (if (and (not (string? login-response))
             login-response)
      (callback-true)
      (if callback-false 
        (callback-false)
        (json-response (str "{\"auth\":" login-response "}"), 401)))))

(defn create [user logged-in-user body public?]
  (if (= logged-in-user user)
    (json-response (post-view/single-post (post/create user body public?)))
    (json-response "{\"auth\":\"can't create post under different logged in user\"}" 401)))

(defroutes routes
  ....
  (PUT "/api/:user/new" request
       (println request)
       (auth? request
              #(create (:user (request :params))
                       (:user (request :session))
                       (:body (get-params request))
                       (:public (get-params request)))))
  ....
)
```

**MODEL**

```
(defn create [username body public?]
  (println public?)
  (when-not (and 
              (str/blank? body)
              (str/blank? username))
  (let [user-id (:id (get-id-from-username username))
        new-post-id
        (:id 
            (sql/with-connection db
                (sql/insert-values :post
              [:usr_id :body :public] [user-id body (Boolean/valueOf public?)])))]
    (by-id new-post-id))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't call `get-params` twice. (request :body) returns a stream, which can't be read twice.

Comment: `(request :body)` is a stream object. Slurping it once read the stream till end, next time there is nothing to read from it

Comment: that is exactly what happened